# If a molecule with 3 chiral centers that are all R, is it the same as the S version?

Tags: stereochemistry

Consider a molecule with 3 chiral centers all marked R. Is this molecule the same as the S version?

Comment: What you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No I don't think both will be the same.They will be enantiomers or non superimposable mirror images of each other.I am sharing a simple trick to find the isomers of a compound with 3 chiral centres instead-

RRR and its enantiomer SSS

SRR and its enantiomer RSS

SSR and its enantiomer RRS

SRS and its enantiomer RSR

With makes a total of 8! You can generalize the formula by 2 raised to the power n (where n is number of chiral centres)